# UITableView additional information before detailed page?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a scenario where my table view output will be in the following format:

INC123  >

INC234  >

INC777  >

When an option is selected, the details about the ticket (selected option) is displayed.

What I would like to have is:

INC123  >

(Short description aboutt this, both under one table cell but the short description can be greyed out or lighter than the ticket number

INC234  >

(Short description about this)

INC777  >

(Short description about this)

Is it possible to implement this? Please guide me on this, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is. Take a look at UITableViewCell's detailTextLabel property.

Comment: What do you mean by output? Output as in console with NSLog or a string object, or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible. Implement this into your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.textLabel.text = INC_STRING_OBJECT;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = INC_STRING_OBJECT.STRING_DESCRIPTION_PROPERTY;
```

Be sure that your storyboard scene for the tableview has cells that are of the "subtitle" type to get access to the detail label.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. You can design your cell in storyboard to include the description labels. Just set the cell to "Custom", drag to make the prototype cell larger, drag `UILabel` objects to the cell and customise.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can configure the text labels. One way is to add a `tag` and access the label with

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:kLabelTag];
```